# azure function - triggered when new event in eventhub, writing it to blob storage - not working, why?

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-eventhub

I have a requirement to read the data from the azure event hub with the help of azure function add timestamp as a value timestamp column and write them to the blob storage. Here is the code snippet i have used

```
using Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace AzureFunctions.SimulatedData
{
    public static class Test
    {
        [FunctionName("Test")]
        public static void Run([EventHubTrigger("samples-workitems", Connection = "EventHubConnectionAppSetting")] EventData[] eventHubMessages, ILogger log)
        {
            foreach (var message in eventHubMessages)
            {
                log.LogInformation($"C# function triggered to process a message: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body)}");
                string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body);

                dynamic dataWithId = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data);
                dataWithId.jobId = "1";
                dataWithId.timeStamp =DateTime.UtcNow;

                //Code to push data in blob
                CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(BlobConnectionString).CreateCloudBlobClient();
                CloudBlockBlob blockBlob= new CloudBlockBlob(new Uri(blobAbsoluteUri), cloudBlobClient);
               
                await blockBlob.UploadTextAsync(blobData);              

                log.LogInformation($"EnqueuedTimeUtc={message.SystemProperties.EnqueuedTimeUtc}");
            }
        }
    }
```

i would request to help and provide some insight as what i need to change or update.

Comment: Hi, Any update?

Comment: Hi T@BowmanZhu i have used a different code and that has worked for me. I tried the same from your end however i had to do a little modification and the same has helped to a great extent

Comment: If you don't have more doubts, can you end this question?:)

Comment: sure please we can and thank you so very much for your kind help

Comment: If my solution works, can you [tick this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSMI2.png) to end this question? It is important to me.:)

Answer (score 0):

Below code should work(Just a simple, works fine on my side.):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace FunctionApp6
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task Run([EventHubTrigger("test1", Connection = "str")] EventData[] eventHubMessages, ILogger log)
        {
            string BlobConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=0730bowmanwindow;AccountKey=xxxxxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
            string containername = "test";
            foreach (var message in eventHubMessages)
            {
                string blobname = "test" + System.Guid.NewGuid() + ".txt";
                log.LogInformation($"C# function triggered to process a message: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body)}");
                string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body);

                //Code to push data in blob
                CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(BlobConnectionString).CreateCloudBlobClient();
                CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(containername);
                CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blobname);
                cloudBlockBlob.UploadTextAsync(data);
                log.LogInformation($"C# function triggered to process a message: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body)}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```